JMM reordering and cache sync memory
public class Cache_01_Sample {

    @JCStressTest
    @Outcome(expect = ACCEPTABLE, desc = "9")
    @Outcome(id = "-1", expect = FORBIDDEN, desc = "0")
    @State
    public static class DemoCache {
        private Map<Integer, Integer> currentMap = new HashMap<>();

        private int size = 100000;

        public DemoCache() {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                currentMap.put(i, i);
            }
        }

        @Actor
        public void get(I_Result result) {
            int i = new Random().nextInt(0, size);
            Integer value = this.currentMap.get(i);
            if (null == value) {
                result.r1 = -1;
            } else {
                result.r1 = value;
            }
        }

        @Actor
        public void refresh() {
            Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                map.put(i, i);
            }

            currentMap = map;
        }
    }
}

My test results show that -1 will not occur, but I can't find any theoretical support.
I want know why -1 not occur?

Your tests show that -1 did not occur ... not that it will not occur.  There is no way that you can show that a particular event will not occur simply by testing.  (I haven't looked at whether -1 could occur in theory ...)

What exactly you want to know? Why are you lucky? It can change at any moment.
